# Default CentoOS apache utf-8 encoding doesn't work?

Tags: php, apache, encoding, utf-8, centos

I have default installation of CentOS and Apache, and the problem is that I'm getting encoding issues if   `content="text/html; charset=UTF-8`" isn't set on the webpage. On my local WAMP and on the other hostings that I tried, this page loads fine, probably because utf-8 header is set. Not sure what I'm really supposed to change in httpd.conf, `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` is already there, but doesn't help at all.  I'm trying to set apache to deal with this problem, so changing html isn't an option. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you use database? If so, what is default db collation? Does simple pure html page with, say, cyrillics, shows up properly?

Comment: If I set content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" in html page it works ok, but the default is <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250" />, and I can't change that, it have to stay that way. Other pages with charset="utf-8" work just fine.

Comment: So you want browser to divine into your dreams, spit on the encoding set and use what you dreamed? Unfortunately it soes not work that way. The content will be shown in the encoding set. And meta is more powerful that the Apache directive (which is sent via header.) That said there is no way to force browser to use utf-8 whether there is meta with cp-1250 set in the head.

Comment: Look, that exact page shows just fine, when hosted on my local WAMP, or my other hosting provider. So, I guess, something can be done.